# Sumifs in VBA where all conditions met

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I'm trying to code the following in VBA:

```
=SUMIFS(N2:N29,D2:D29,IF(COUNTIF(D2:D29,A36)=0,"*","="&A36),C2:C29,IF(COUNTIF(C2:C29,B36)=0,"*","="&B36),E2:E29,IF(COUNTIF(E2:E29,C36)=0,"*","="&C36),F2:F29,IF(COUNTIF(F2:F29,D36)=0,"*","="&D36))
```

The nested If and Countif are there so the Sumif ignores any condition that isn't required by the user (the user inputs A:B36), but still sums cells that meet all the remaining conditions.

I've written the following in VBA (with criterias 1-3 determined in the same way):

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("V" & i), Box4.Value) = 0 Then
    criteria4 = "*"
Else
    criteria4 = "=" & Box4.Value
End If

If criteria1 = "*" And criteria2 = "*" And criteria3 = "*" And criteria4 = "*" Then
    dummy = 0
Else
    dummy = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("H" & i), Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("S" & i), criteria1, Worksheets("Benchmark") _
    .Range("R" & i), criteria2, Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("C" & i), criteria3, Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("V" & i), criteria4)
```

The `sumifs` is summing all cells that meet at least one of the conditions supplied, rather than all of them.

To add context, the purpose of this code is to loop through a range, and find cells that meet criteria supplied by the user. However, if the user opts to supply certain criteria but not others, then those criteria not supplied are ignored. I've used a sumifs because my understanding is that the function will sum all cells that meet the set of criteria supplied. I can then say, if sumifs>0 then cell meets criteria supplied by the user.

Comment: Just checking: Have you tried using the formula without the VBA to check that the formula itself is working as expected?

Comment: Hi Mistella - Thanks for replying. Yes I have, it works fine in the spreadsheet...

Comment: Where are you setting `i`?  Is it a single number, or part of a range (e.g. `"3:H10"`)?

Comment: So what I've posted is nested within a for loop, for i = 2 to LastRow

Comment: Also - your Excel and VBA formula are pointing to completely different columns?  Is this deliberate, or have you mis-posted one of them?

Comment: Why are you using SumIfs for a single row?

Comment: It's deliberate, the two are going through different sheets in the workbook

Comment: Rory - Because I need to know, for each cell in that column, does it meet the criteria supplied by the user. If it does, then the sumifs  will return >0 and I know that the cell contains information that I need (I made a slight edit to my original question explaining)

Comment: What is the value in Column H?  Would you be better off using `CountIfs` instead of `SumIfs`?

Comment: The values in H are ISINs. What would the countifs solution look like? My initial thought is that the countifs wouldn't be able to deal with instances where the user fails to supply a certain value...in that case the corresponding countif would just return 0, and what I'd want is the countif to be ignored

Comment: . . .  Like the `SumIfs` version, but with the first argument (i.e. Column H) omitted.  So, `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("S" & i), criteria1, Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("R" & i), criteria2, Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("C" & i), criteria3, Worksheets("Benchmark").Range("V" & i), criteria4))`

Comment: okay this makes intuitive sense, but if the user fails to supply some criteria how would the function evaluate? (sorry, showing my noobyness a bit)

Comment: That doesn't require `Sumifs` - you can use `Like` in code to test the relevant columns.

Comment: Thanks for replying Rory, very much appreciated. I'm unfamiliar with this workaround, do you have the time to elaborate slightly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version bodged together based on additional information garnered through the comments, that dispenses with the `SumIfs` entirely:

```
Dim dummy AS Long, IsValid AS Boolean

For i = 2 to LastRow
    If Box1.Value & Box2.Value & Box2.Value & Box4.Value = "****" Then
        dummy = 0
    Else
        IsValid = (Worksheets("Benchmark").Cells(i, "S").Value LIKE Box1.Value) 
        IsValid = IsValid And (Worksheets("Benchmark").Cells(i, "R").Value LIKE Box2.Value) 
        IsValid = IsValid And (Worksheets("Benchmark").Cells(i, "C").Value LIKE Box3.Value) 
        IsValid = IsValid And (Worksheets("Benchmark").Cells(i, "V").Value LIKE Box4.Value) 

        If IsValid Then
            dummy = Worksheets("Benchmark").Cells(i, "H").Value
        Else
            dummy = 0
        End If
    End If

    'Code to do stuff with dummy goes here

Next i
```

For each iteration of the `For` loop, we are using a Boolean variable to track if the row is valid, and `LIKE` statements to check each criteria.  The 2nd comparison onwards use `AND` to make sure that you remember if the criteria has already failed.

A `LIKE` statement is similar to an `=` statement, but allows Wildcards - so, for example `"SomeText" = "SomeOtherText"` and `"SomeText" LIKE "SomeOtherText"` will both be `False`, whereas `"Some*Text" = "SomeOtherText"` will be `False` while `"Some*Text" LIKE "SomeOtherText"` will be `True` - since the `"*"` means "any text can go here".

(`SumIfs` uses a `LIKE` comparison instead of an `=` comparison, unless you specifically specify `=` at the start of the Condition.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. Just so I understand correctly, will this code only check for criteria that are supplied by the user? And ignore any that aren't supplied?

Comment: So I suppose there are two things; the code has to ignore any conditions not supplied by the user, and only evaluate as True if all conditions that are supplied are satisfied

Comment: @Jerbs If the `Box#.Value` is `"*"` when the user has not specified a criteria, then *that* check will automatically evaluate as `True` (since `Variable LIKE "*"` means "Variable is anything, including an empty string") unless your variable contains an error code.  (In which case, you will get a "Type Mismatch" error)